# Can't run PHP::SVM

Tags: php, machine-learning, data-mining, svm, libsvm

I tried to run a basic SVM [example from official PHP::SVM tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/svm.examples.php), adding a few echo methods and turning on error reporting:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '1';
$data = array(
    array(-1, 1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2),
    array(1, 1 => 0.22, 5 => 0.01, 94 => 0.11),
);
echo '2';
$svm = new SVM();
echo '3';
$model = $svm->train($data);
echo '4';
$data = array(1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2);
$result = $model->predict($data);
var_dump($result);
$model->save('model.svm');
echo '5';
?>
```

Running this script on my local machine displays "12". What is the problem with this line?

```
$svm = new SVM();
```

And how do I run this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing creating the SVM class and most of the time is because it is not installed. If you try using php-cli you would get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'SVM' not found in /tmp/svm.php on line 9
```

To install the extension (on Ubuntu 12.04) I did the following:

```
# Install pear so we can get it from the common repo

$sudo apt-get install php-pear

#Install the headers for libsvm

$sudo apt-get install libsvm-dev

# Install the actual extension, I had to force it because it wasn't marked as stable

$sudo pecl install -f svm

#Then add the extension=svm.so line to the php.ini

$vi php.ini

# Now when you run it, you would get an actual output:

$php --php-ini ./php.ini svm.php

1234float(-1)
5
```